# How can I make my mongo update query the most efficient?

Tags: mongodb

I have a large test database I am using to test my queries, and I am wondering how I can possibly go about making this update query much more efficient as it is terrible right now. Here is what I have so far:

```
const query = {
  username:"billyBob", 
  socialPlatform:"twitter", 
  userUrl:"www.whoami.com"
};

const updateDoc = {
  $set: { 
    'posts.0.sentiment': 'positive' 
  }
}

db.socialContent.update(query, updateDoc);
```

Here is an example doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1234567890"),
    "socialPlatform" : "twitter",
    "username" : "billyBob",
    "userUrl" : "www.whoami.com",
    "posts" : [
        {
            "location" : "USA",
            "timezone" : "CST",
            "sentiment" : "perplexed",
            "tweetLink" : "https://www.tweetlink.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

username `billyBob` has thousands of posts for this specific social platform.

Comment: do you have an index on `username`? can you add `db.colupdate(...).explain()` results for your update query?

Comment: If your `posts` array may have thousands of elements per document and you are updating these individually, an obvious efficiency/performance improvement would be to use smaller documents. For more background see: [Why shouldn't I embed large arrays in my documents?](http://www.askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays/) and [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1).

Comment: @Stennie Thats a good article. However, I'm practicing on a test database that is similar to a production database I will not have much input into regarding how it is setup, so working within these limits is still my main goal.

Comment: @Saravana there is an index on _id, which should help.

Comment: An index on `_id` isn't relevant unless that is part of the query criteria for your update. In your example query a suitable index might be `{ username: 1, socialPlatform:1}` (presuming that this combination is sufficient to uniquely identify a user). If you are unable to influence the design of the `posts` array (having thousands of items), that is going to be an unfortunate limiting factor for performance and efficiency. What specific version of MongoDB server are you using?